# Lightning Message Channel deletion from 2GP or isExpose change to false

Tags: security-review, second-generation-packaging

we failed security review of second-generation managed package because Lightning Message Channel (LMC) has isExposed=true. It should be false. The value of isExposed is **not possible to change** to false, that's why we created new LMC, refactored code to use new one and now we need to **delete** old LMC (isExposed=true) , but it is **not possible**.

**We are in deadlock situation.** We don't have possibility to change isExposed for existing LMC and we can not delete LMC.

Please, did you have something similar? What is the way out of this?

Thanks

Comment: Did your package contain any visualforce components?
If so did you have any issues with your visualforce components/pages not being able to access the message channel once set to isExposed = false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2GP allows the deletion of metadata components. You can raise a support case with Salesforce and get the component deleted.

Before you attempt this, you must ask Salesforce to enable this feature.

Start by logging a case at the Salesforce Partner Community.

Check out details via the documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_remove_md_components.htm

See section with Lightning Message Channel https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_lightning_message_channel

Looks like if component removal is enabled by SF then it is possible to remove.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I checked list of components which can be removed in article you sent me and LightningMessageChannel is not there. I wanted to enroll to pilot program for removal of components from 2GP but SF support sent me answer that it would not help me to remove LightningMessageChannel anyway.

Comment: If it cannot be removed, please make sure to have an empty file and remove all code and then document it saying it's false positive.

Comment: I found https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_lightning_message_channel which looks like Lightning Message Channel is possible to remove when you have enabled component removal feature for 2GP. Thanks Mohith

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : I have a similar question , how to delete or set isExposed to false for a messaging channel in 1GP package? The package is in review and fails due to messaging channel issue.